# Как найти все теги по вхождению в название класса с помощью BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Дана структура:

```
<td class='1234_sfsfs'><span eu='333'></span></td>
<td class='1234_fddfd'><span eu='fkdjnv'></span></td>
<td class='1234_bjnieujrini'><span eu='kdfjnvk'></span></td>
<td class='11234_fddfd'><span eu='dkdv'></span></td>
<td class='fddfd'><span eu='vd'></span></td>
```

Как можно с помощью BeautifulSoup найти все теги `td` у которых в названии класса есть `'1234_'`, далее внутри них найти тег `<span>` у него уже достать имя атрибута `eu`

`soup.find_all('td', class_='?')find('span').get('eu')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_doc = """<td class='1234_sfsfs' eu='333'></td>
<td class='1234_fddfd' eu='fsvs'></td>
<td class='1234_bjnieujrini' eu='bbbbc'></td>
<td class='11234_fddfd' eu='fsvs'></td>
<td class='fddfd'></td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')


links = [item['eu'] for item in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':re.compile("1234_")})]

for i in links:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Чуть отредактировал вопрос, вы случайно не знаете как можно изменить код, чтобы достать eu уже у внутреннего span? Спасибо

Comment: links = [item for item in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':re.compile("1234_")})] -> links = [item['eu'] for item in links.find('span"))] - вот так попробовал, не сработало

Comment: разобрался, вот так дополнил: links = [item.find('span").get('eu') for item in links)] - спасибо